# ltng:require efficiency

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

Say I have multiple components that require the same dependency to be loaded, does `ltng:require` perform accurate dependency management?
I.e. does it guarantee that the dependencies are loaded only once across different components?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, as per the documentation [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/ltng:require/documentation)
The resources only load once if they are specified in multiple  tags in the same component or across different components.

Comment: Missed that, thanks.